# Accepting login number with changing prefix with PHP

Tags: php, forms, authentication, prefix, exact-match

I have a flatfile database file with the following numbers:

```
1
2
3
4
5
etc.
```

The numbers correspond to a USER ID where a person would enter any of those numbers above, in order to login.

I do not want to modify my file. My question is, if there's a way to add an accepted "PREFIX".

For example, a user logs in with:

```
abcd1
abcd2
abcd3
abcd4
abcd5
etc.
```

But my data file is still, but does not contain the prefix "abcd":

```
1
2
3
4
5
etc.
```

It would also have to be a "perfect" match. The tests I have done so far have not been conclusive

I guess using an accepted "array" would be the way to go?

My present login PHP script is this, but **only works on an exact match** for a number, I would like to add a prefix that I can change later on:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
$today = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m"), date("d"), date("y"));

$currenttime = date('h:i:s:u');
list($hrs,$mins,$secs,$msecs) = split(':',$currenttime);

echo "<center><form action=\"" . $PHP_SELF . "\" method='post'><input onkeypress=\"return isNumberKey(event)\" type='text' name='uNum' /><input type='submit' value='Submit' /></form></center>";

if(!$_POST['uNum']) {
die('<center>Entrer votre numéro d\'inscription pour finaliser votre demande.</center>');
}

$numbers = file_get_contents("datafile.txt");

$uNumber = $_POST['uNum'];

if ( @preg_match( "/([^0-9]{$uNumber}[^0-9])/", $numbers ) ) {

print_r( "<center>The number $uNumber is good. You may proceed.</b><br><br>" );

file_put_contents($_POST['uNum'].".txt",$_POST['uNum'] . "\nUsed on ".date("m/d/Y", $today). (" $hrs:$mins:$secs")."");

include 'validate_process.php';

if (isset($_POST['uNumber']))
{

$uNumber = $_GET['inscripnum1'];
}

} else {
echo "<center>Sorry, this login number does not exist.</center>";
}

?>
```

Comment: Why not change your preg: `preg_match('/^' . preg_quote($uNumber, '/') . '$/m', $numbers)` to match a number that spans the whole line

Comment: @Jack Thanks, this one worked. Yet, yow can add a line where I can change an accepted prefix?

Comment: thanks for like the 10th downvoted question, pffft - whatever turns your crank, great! whatever you're trying to do, it's not working. You obviously love to keep your precious points downvoting my questions but not my answer. You funny animal.

Comment: You downvoters are really going to have to explain your downvotes, really. I don't care for the points lost, I care about a valid reason. This is an over year old question.

Answer (score 1):

Before you do a preg_match, check if the input has the desired prefix and remove it.

```
$uNumber = $_POST['uNum'];

$prefix = "abcd"; //you can change the prefix anytime
$length = strlen($prefix);
if(substr($uNumber, 0, $length) === $prefix) {
    $uNumber = substr($uNumber,$length);
} else {
    $uNumber = ""; //empty or some value that is not a valid ID stored in your flatfile.
}

//Now use $uNumber in preg_match()

if ( @preg_match( "/([^0-9]{$uNumber}[^0-9])/", $numbers ) ) {
    //do something
}
```

Comment: Thanks Manu. This seems to be the way to go, in order for me to change the prefix later on, however I can't seem to get it working right, as to the "where" to put it in my script. Any chance of a rewrite?

Comment: @Fred - Put the code before your `if` condition, have amended answer to reflect the same.

Comment: I just did that now, and it's accepting anything I put inside it.

Comment: Checkout http://codepad.org/e08YV8sa, can you gives some inputs that gave false positives.

Comment: I managed to get the script working, thank you. Now I have another problem. Once the number was entered, I had a routine which would delete the number that was used, but this no longer works with your routine:

    $bodycont = preg_replace("/\b({$_POST['inscripnum']})\b\n/","",$index);

    $fh = fopen("datafile.txt","w");
    fwrite($fh,$bodycont);
    fclose($fh);

How can I implement finding and replacing (deleting) the entry that was used?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

`if ( @preg_match( "/([^0-9]{abcd$uNumber}[^0-9])/", $numbers ) ||  @preg_match( "/([^0-9]{$uNumber}[^0-9])/", $numbers ) )`

Think that'll work? I never use preg_match

Comment: Thanks, it kind of worked. Only thing is that, if I enter just the number "2", it accepts it.

Comment: yeah i thought you wanted both. like abcd2 and just 2. If you want just abcd2, then just remove `|| @preg_match( "/([^0-9]{$uNumber}[^0-9])/", $numbers )`

Answer (score 0):

This is one of many ways to do it. Create an array of the file contents and loop through that array:

```
$numbers = file('datafile.txt');
$result = false;
foreach($numbers as $n) {
  if ('abcd'.$n === $uNumber) {
    $result = true;
    break;
  } 
}

if ($result) {
  // OK!
}
```

Here's another, where I load the file as an array, add the prefix to each element and then check if the provided value is in that array:

```
$numbers = file('datafile.txt');
$result = in_array($uNumber,
                   array_map(function($e) { return 'abcd'.$e; },
                             $numbers)
                  );
```